# how would I add inline html to this erb image tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to add this html data tag inline

```
data-zoom-image="<% image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large) %>"
```

to this erb tag, but am unsure how I would go about this. Any ideas?

```
<%= image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:medium), id: "iconnection#{n}") %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass it in like `data: { zoom_image: "large/image1.jpg" }` and the data attribute gets converted to `data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"`.

Try:

```
<%= image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:medium), id: "iconnection#{n}", data: { zoom_image: "large/image1.jpg" }) %>
```

**Update:**

I think you want to output the result of:
`<% image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>` instead of just interpreting it.

Try:

```
data: { zoom_image: "#{ image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) }" }
```

Comment: I'm sure you got an error as I just noticed a typo in my answer.  Sorry about that, there is a missing parenthesis.  Updated the answer, please give it a try.

Comment: Yes, this was the appropriate syntax. Thanks!